# AssertionError: Could not compute output Tensor("dense/Sigmoid:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I am trying to create a multi branch CNN-LSTM model. I have created 4 models and concatenate it. I am getting the assertion error. Here is my code.

```
top_words= 50
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=top_words)

# Pad all sequences
padded_inputs = pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=top_words, value = 0.0)
padded_inputs_test = pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=top_words, value = 0.0)

# create the model
embedding_vecor_length = 32

model1_input = keras.Input(shape= 250)
model2_input = keras.Input(shape= 250)
model3_input = keras.Input(shape= 250)
model4_input = keras.Input(shape= 250)

embedding_layer = Embedding(top_words, embedding_vecor_length)

encoded_model1_input = embedding_layer(model1_input)
encoded_model2_input = embedding_layer(model2_input)
encoded_model3_input = embedding_layer(model3_input)
encoded_model4_input = embedding_layer(model4_input)

model1 = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu', 
kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01) )(encoded_model1_input)
model1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(model1)
model1 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.4)(model1)
model1 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(model1)
model1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(128))(model1)

model2 = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=5, padding='same', activation='relu', 
kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01) )(encoded_model2_input)
model2 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(model2)
model2 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.4)(model2)
model2 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(model2)
model2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(128))(model2)

model3 = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=7, padding='same', activation='relu', 
kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01) )(encoded_model3_input)
model3 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(model3)
model3 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.4)(model3)
model3 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(model3)
model3 = Bidirectional(LSTM(128))(model3)

model4 = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=9, padding='same', activation='relu', 
kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01) )(encoded_model3_input)
model4 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(model4)
model4 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.4)(model4)
model4 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(model4)
model4 = Bidirectional(LSTM(128))(model4)

abc = keras.layers.concatenate([model1, model2, model3, model4])
out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(abc)

model = keras.Model(inputs=[model1_input, model2_input, model3_input,model4_input], outputs=[out])

rmsprop= optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.01, decay=0.1)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer= rmsprop, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()


model.fit(padded_inputs, y_train, epochs=15, verbose=True, validation_split= 0.2)
```

[Model Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlVJB.png)

What's wrong with this code. I am not getting exactly what I am doing wrong. Am I doing something wrong with **model.fit()** Please help

Comment: please add fit call and error message

Comment: `model.fit(padded_inputs, y_train, epochs=15, verbose=True, validation_split= 0.2)`

Comment: Error Message:

 AssertionError: Could not compute output Tensor("dense/Sigmoid:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AssertionError: Could not compute output Tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61997378/assertionerror-could-not-compute-output-tensor)

Comment: @OwaisAnwar Is this still an issue for you? else you could try as mentioned [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/14197). Thanks!