# Could not compute output KerasTensor in multi modal seq2seq

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, python, keras, seq2seq

I am trying to generate comments from subreddit posts using **images, titles, and source subreddit** of the post.

if you don't know what a subreddit is, just think about it as a category of the post e.g cats, dogs, cars

I am using CNN for images, a simple neural network for subreddits, LSTM for titles, and finally LSTM for comment generation.

I made it work but it was hard to code inference part, so I refactored it so each component of the final model is a small model.
But when I try to put everything together I am getting an error shown below.

How can I fix it and what is the cause of the problem?

### Error

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_42/2610877267.py in <module>
      5 inputs = encoder.inputs
      6 
----> 7 result = decoder(decoder_target, encoder(inputs))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    950     if _in_functional_construction_mode(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_list):
    951       return self._functional_construction_call(inputs, args, kwargs,
--> 952                                                 input_list)
    953 
    954     # Maintains info about the `Layer.call` stack.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _functional_construction_call(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_list)
   1089         # Check input assumptions set after layer building, e.g. input shape.
   1090         outputs = self._keras_tensor_symbolic_call(
-> 1091             inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
   1092 
   1093         if outputs is None:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call(self, inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
    820       return nest.map_structure(keras_tensor.KerasTensor, output_signature)
    821     else:
--> 822       return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
    823 
    824   def _infer_output_signature(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _infer_output_signature(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
    861           # TODO(kaftan): do we maybe_build here, or have we already done it?
    862           self._maybe_build(inputs)
--> 863           outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    864 
    865         self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py in call(self, inputs, training, mask)
    423     """
    424     return self._run_internal_graph(
--> 425         inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    426 
    427   def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py in _run_internal_graph(self, inputs, training, mask)
    567     for x in self.outputs:
    568       x_id = str(id(x))
--> 569       assert x_id in tensor_dict, 'Could not compute output ' + str(x)
    570       output_tensors.append(tensor_dict[x_id].pop())
    571 

AssertionError: Could not compute output KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 80, 5000), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='dense_25/truediv:0', description="created by layer 'dense_25'")
```

### Title encoder

Takes tokenized title of the post embeded it and returns state of the LSTM.

```
def build_title_embeddings():
    encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(max_title_len), name='Post title')
    encoder_emb =  Embedding(vocab_size, title_embedding_size)(encoder_inputs)
    encoder = LSTM(title_hidden_size, return_state=True)
    _, state_h, state_c = encoder(encoder_emb)
    
    return Model(inputs=encoder_inputs, outputs=[state_h, state_c], name="Title encoder")
```

### Cnn

Cnn pretrained on imagenet from `keras.applications.EfficientNetB3`

```
def build_cnn():
    cnn = EfficientNetB3(include_top=False, input_shape=(300,300,3), pooling="avg")
    cnn.trainable = False
    return Model(inputs=cnn.inputs, outputs=cnn.outputs, name="cnn")
```

### Subreddit embedding

Takes as input one hot encoded vector.
It pupose is reduce dimentionality of the input

```
def build_subreddit_embeddings():
    input_subreddit = Input(shape=(num_subreddits), name='One hot encoded subreddit')
    sub_emb = Dense(subreddit_embedding_size, activation='relu')(input_subreddit)
    
    return Model(inputs=input_subreddit, outputs=sub_emb, name="Subreddit embedding")
```

### Final encoder

Takes everything above and produce initial state for the decoder

```
def build_final_encoder():
    cnn = build_cnn()
    subreddit_embeddings = build_subreddit_embeddings()
    title_embeddings = build_title_embeddings()
    
    merged = Concatenate()([cnn.output, subreddit_embeddings.output, *title_embeddings.output])

    intermediate_layer = Dense(intermediate_layer_size, activation='relu')(merged)

    state1 = Dense(decoder_hidden_size, activation='relu')(intermediate_layer)
    state2 = Dense(decoder_hidden_size, activation='relu')(intermediate_layer)

    return Model(inputs=[cnn.inputs, subreddit_embeddings.inputs, title_embeddings.inputs], outputs=[state1,state2], name="post_encoder")
```

### Decoder

Takes as an input output of the final encoder and produces comment tokens.

decoders inputs are previous tokens predicted by itself

```
def build_decoder():
    decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(max_decoder_len,), name="Decoder inputs")

    state_inputs1 = Input(shape=(decoder_hidden_size,), name="Decoder state input 1")
    state_inputs2 = Input(shape=(decoder_hidden_size,), name="Decoder state input 2")

    decoder_emb =  Embedding(vocab_size, decoder_embedding_size)(decoder_inputs)

    decoder_lstm = LSTM(decoder_hidden_size, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name="decoder_lstm")
    
    decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_emb, initial_state=[state_inputs1, state_inputs2])
    
    decoder_outputs = Dense(vocab_size, activation="softmax")(decoder_outputs)
    
    return Model(inputs=[decoder_inputs, [state_inputs1,state_inputs2]], outputs=decoder_outputs, name="final_decoder")
```

## Attempt of bringing everything together

Decoder target is correct tokens ids shifted by one during training and previous prediction during inference

e.g. during training

###### Decoder target - `['<start_of_sentence_token>','I','like','pizza']`

###### Correct answer - `['I','like','pizza','<end_of_sentence_token>']`

````
decoder_target = Input(shape=(max_decoder_len,), name="Decoder target")

encoder = build_final_encoder()
decoder = build_decoder()
inputs = encoder.inputs

result = decoder(decoder_target, encoder(inputs)) # Errors happen here
```
````

Comment: Hi, Could you provide the same code as complete GIST too?  Attaching similar issues with similar Error stack trace . https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34912   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61997378/assertionerror-could-not-compute-output-tensor